# Why is my discretized transfer function unstable when my discretized state-space model is stable?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, transfer-function, state-space

I am working with a 30-state, 14-input linear model that is described by a state-space model:

```
model_state_space = ss(A, B, C, D);
```

The model is extremely slow (it describes the thermal behavior of a building), so when I discretize it I choose a sample time of 900 seconds and plot the step response from one of the inputs:

```
[y,t] = step(model_state_space);
plot(t, y(:,:,end))
```

[image]

I obtain a similar plot when I compute the step response of the discretized state-space model, or of the equivalent transfer function continuous model:

```
hold on
[y,t] = step(c2d(model_state_space, 900));
plot(t,y(:,:,end), 'r')
[y,t] = step(tf(model_state_space));
plot(t,y(:,:,end), 'k')
```

[image]

But when I compute the impulse response of the discretized transfer function, the system appears unstable:

```
[y,t] = step(c2d(tf(model_state_space), 900));
plot(t,y(:,:,end), 'g')
```

[image]

Can someone please explain why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a thread on MATLAB Central that deals with exactly this problem: http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/7746

Comment: It would be helpful to at least provide a brief summary of the answer there so this will still be useful in the future of the link dies.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a high order model so you might be running into numerical precision issues.

Make sure the realization of model_state_space is minimal. You can do this with

```
min_model_state_space = minreal(model_state_space)
```

Also, not all state-space realizations are created equally. Some have better numerical properties, such as a balanced realization:

```
[balanced_model_state_space, G] = balreal(model_state_space)
```

If the vector G contains small values it means you can reduce the order of your model without giving up accuracy. Look up the matlab function *balred*.

Just from looking at your step response plot you probably don't need a 30th order model (1st or 2nd order might even be enough).